# How do I install ntpstat in Ubuntu?

Tags: apt, ntp

I want to install ntpstat in Ubuntu for checking if NTP is working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using Ubuntu 15.04 Vivid it is now packaged and installable using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install ntpstat
```

If you are using 14.10 or older you can try downloading the package from:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/ntpstat

and install the deb file using the following command (using the appropiate file path and 64/32bit version in the file name):

```
sudo dpkg -i ntpstat_0.0.0.1-1_amd64.deb
```

I tested the above method for 14.10 and ntpstat did not pull in any extra dependancies for me, but YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

You can install it by apt-get:

```
sudo apt-get install ntpstat
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ntpstat) in Launchpad. It might be unstable. Download the deb file suited to your computer and install it using:

```
sudo dpkg -i <path-to-downloaded-deb-package>
```